# Spring Boot controllers are returning a 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot controllers are returning a 404 on all endpoints

trying to get basic controller returning data
Package structure is setup correctly all packages are sub packages of the main package
annotations look fine been using spring casually for a bit but im clueless im expecting at least hello world im assuming its some spring garbage goin on with it not finding the bean idk  no luck finding anything out of conventional configuration. plz help thanks

```
package com.bookieburglar.api.services;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.bookieburlgar.api.services")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bookieburglar.api.services")
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookieBurglarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookieBurglarApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Odds.java

```
package com.bookieburglar.api.services.models;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Odds {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("sport_key")
    private String sport_key;

    @JsonProperty("sport_title")
    private String sport_title;

    @JsonProperty("commence_time")
    private String commence_time;

    @JsonProperty("home_team")
    private String home_team;

    @JsonProperty("away_team")
    private String away_team;

    @JsonProperty("bookmakers")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "odds_id")
    private List<Bookmaker> bookmakers;


    public Odds(String id, String sportKey, String sportTitle, String commenceTime,
            String homeTeam, String awayTeam, List<Bookmaker> bookmakers) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sport_key = sportKey;
        this.sport_title = sportTitle;
        this.commence_time = commenceTime;
        this.home_team = homeTeam;
        this.away_team = awayTeam;
        this.bookmakers = bookmakers;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSportKey() {
        return sport_key;
    }

    public void setSportKey(String sportKey) {
        this.sport_key = sportKey;
    }

    public String getSportTitle() {
        return sport_title;
    }

    public void setSportTitle(String sportTitle) {
        this.sport_title = sportTitle;
    }

    public String getCommenceTime() {
        return commence_time;
    }

    public void setCommenceTime(String commenceTime) {
        this.commence_time = commenceTime;
    }

    public String getHomeTeam() {
        return home_team;
    }

    public void setHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
        this.home_team = homeTeam;
    }

    public String getAwayTeam() {
        return away_team;
    }

    public void setAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
        this.away_team = awayTeam;
    }

    public List<Bookmaker> getBookmakers() {
        return bookmakers;
    }

    public void setBookmakers(List<Bookmaker> bookmakers) {
        this.bookmakers = bookmakers;
    }
}
```

OddsController

```
package com.bookieburglar.api.services.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bookieburglar.api.services.services.OddsAPIService;
import com.bookieburglar.api.services.services.OddsService;
import com.bookieburglar.api.services.models.Odds;
import com.bookieburglar.api.services.repositories.OddsRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Odds")
public class OddsController {

    
    

    @Autowired
    private OddsService oddsService;
    
    
    
    
    
    @Autowired
    private OddsAPIService oddsAPIService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getOdds() {
        return "WORLD";
        //return (List<Odds>) OddsRepository.findAll();
    }

//    @GetMapping("/{id}")
//    public Odds getOdds(@PathVariable String id) {
//        return OddsRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
//    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Odds createOdds(@RequestBody Odds Odds) {
        System.out.println("frthoo");
        return oddsService.saveOdds(Odds);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/refresh")
    @ResponseBody
    public String refreshOdds() {
        System.out.println("ttgb5");
        //return oddsAPIService.refreshOdds(); 
        return "yoo";
    }

//    @PutMapping("/{id}")
//    public Odds updateOdds(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Odds Odds) {
//        Odds.setId(id);
//        return OddsRepository.save(Odds);
//    }
//
//    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
//    public void deleteOdds(@PathVariable String id) {
//        OddsRepository.deleteById(id);
//    }
    
    
}
```

OddsServices

```
package com.bookieburglar.api.services.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.bookieburglar.api.services.models.Odds;
import com.bookieburglar.api.services.repositories.OddsRepository;

@Service
public class OddsService {

    
    @Autowired
    private OddsRepository oddsRepository;

    public List<Odds> getAllOdds() {
        return (List<Odds>) oddsRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Odds> findOddsById(String id) {
        return oddsRepository.findById(id);
    }
//    public List<Odds> findOddsBySportTitle(String sportTitle) {
//        return oddsRepository.findBySportTitle(sportTitle);
//    }
//
//    public List<Odds> findOddsByHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
//        return oddsRepository.findByHomeTeam(homeTeam);
//    }
//    
//    public List<Odds> findOddsByAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
//        return oddsRepository.findByAwayTeam(awayTeam);
//    }

    public Odds saveOdds(Odds odds) {
        return oddsRepository.save(odds);
    }

    public void deleteOdds(String id) {
        oddsRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

OddsRepository

```
package com.bookieburglar.api.services.repositories;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.bookieburglar.api.services.models.Odds;


@Repository
public interface OddsRepository extends JpaRepository<Odds, String> {

    

    
    List<Odds> findAll();
    // additional methods can be defined here, for example, to search for odds by sport key or teams 
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bookieburglar.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Bookie Burglar</name>
    <description>API for BookieBurglar</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please share the curl/ URL you are hitting

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Odds/ with a slash at the end
method = GET

Answer (score 0):

In **@ComponentScan** annotation. Package name is incorrect.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bookieburlgar.api.services")
```

It should be

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.**bookieburglar**.api.services")

Comment: Thanks good catch. Now the app fails to start. I didnt make an other changes besides the one suggested.  ````Description:

Field oddsRepository in com.bookieburglar.api.services.services.OddsService required a bean of type 'com.bookieburglar.api.services.repositories.OddsRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.bookieburglar.api.services.repositories.OddsRepository' in your configuration.
````

Comment: Please remove @EnableJpaRepositories annotation. That is not required

Comment: And because of this only error is coming

Comment: i commented out that error (updated the code above) went away now I have this one ````org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oddsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oddsService': Error creating bean with name 'oddsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oddsRepository': Error creating bean with name 'oddsRepository' defined in com.bookieburglar.api.services.repositories.OddsRepository...
````

Comment: Can you please share application.properties file? Also please remove javax.persistence-api dependency from pom.xml

Comment: With Spring Boot, the annotation for where to scan for source isn't required, unless you have defined your sources in a separate package than from where you have defiened your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: @vegaasen - you are right, here the problem in the annotation that’s why I gave answer to fix that but that annotation is not required at all

Comment: Thanks all I was using javax for my annotations with hibernate 6 which moved to jakarta, switched that and it working like i intend